# Creating n number of circles on google map with ng-maps

Tags: angularjs

I've read a few other posts that are similar in nature on SO, but I still don't understand what I have done wrong.

I want to create multiple circles on a google map from a json string configured like:

```
[
    {"name":"0","lat":30.45,"long":91.15},
    {"name":"1","lat":0.0,"long":0.0},
    {"name":"5","lat":0.0,"long":0.0}
]
```

I am hoping I can just iterate through the string and set the respective values. 
The variable geofences is bound to the containing div with the ng-app declaration.
This is my current try:

```
<ng-map class=map zoom="15" center="[30.45, -91.15]">
    <marker position="[30.45, -91.15]" />   
    <shape 
        ng-repeat="fence in geofences" 
        name="{{fence.name}}" 
        radius="40" 
        center="[{{fence.lat}}, {{fence.long}}]" 
        radius="40" />
    <control name="overviewMap" opened="true" />
</ng-map>
```

I expect it has something to do with getting the values from a variable as if I hard code a value it works

This is what the Chrome developer console output:

> angular.js:12332 TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

and at the very bottom of the stack trace:

`<shape ng-repeat="fence in geofences" name="{{fence.name}}" center="[{{fence.lat}}, {{fence.long}}]" radius="40" class="ng-scope >`

What have I done incorrectly or worst case scenario how could I do something like this?

Comment: What is wrong with your current results?   ARe you getting an error?

Comment: I do not see a circle on the map; granted, I only expect to see one since it does not have coordinates of 0,0. There are errors in the console in chrome

Comment: @Hardrock302 - Please add the errors to your question. The more info you give us, the more likely you'll get an answer...

Comment: I'm not seeing any call to `id` anywhere. Add the code that shows where you're calling this `id` property, and where it's defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you are getting this error since `google.maps.Circle` object could not be created. `shape` directive expects `name` attribute that corresponds to map object (see below list), the provided values (e.g. `"0"` or `"1"`) are invalid

The list of *supported* shape names:

- `circle`
- `polygon`
- `polyline`
- `rectangle`
- `groundOverlay`
- `image`

So, since your goal is to display circles, specify for `name` attribute `cicrle` value:

```
<shape ng-repeat="fence in geofences"
           name="circle"
           radius="40"
           center="[{{fence.lat}}, {{fence.long}}]"
     />
```

**Example**

```js
var app = angular.module('mapApp', ['ngMap']);
app.controller('mapCntrl', function ($scope) {
    
    $scope.geofences = [
        { "name": "circle", "lat": 30.45, "long": -91.15 }
    ];

});
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=placeses,visualization,drawing,geometry,places"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps/master/build/scripts/ng-map.js"></script>
<div ng-app="mapApp" ng-controller="mapCntrl">
    <ng-map class=map zoom="15" center="[30.45, -91.15]">
        <marker position="[30.45, -91.15]" />
        <shape ng-repeat="fence in geofences"
               name="circle"
               radius="40"
               center="[{{fence.lat}}, {{fence.long}}]"
         />
        <control name="overviewMap" opened="true" />
    </ng-map>
</div>
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ww8rsNWUlB3iIYD9sP9p?p=preview)